# Azure App Service -- Web.config changes being overwritten

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.0

I have made changes to the web.config via Kudu for a .NET core 3.0 application running on Azure App Service, yet it seems when the site is deployed via Azure pipelines those changes I've made within the web.config is overwritten.

Our solution (.sln) doesn't include or have a web.config file.

Am I meant to explicitly include a web.config within our project and then that wouldn't occur?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Regarding this question, I hope my answer is helpful to you.^-^

Comment: I'd also like to know since I'm using web.config to enable double escape sequencing in the URL. Azure App Service doesn't expose that capability in the Configuration page.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Configuration\web.config">
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

For more details, you can refer to the content of these two websites.

1、  https://github.com/dotnet/websdk/issues/564

2、 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162961/aspnet-core-app-with-a-webconfig-cannot-use-iis-ex.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to have web.config file in root directory. I had to put web.config for a angular app on app service. Also, using the web.config values in App Service is not recommended. Use the Configuration link on app service (see screenshot below) to store app settings and connection strings. The values in app service configuration override the ones specified in web.config file. This way you keep your config values for different env separate and manageable. If you still want to use web.config values, you can have web.config transform in your solution to transform web.config for different envs. That way you can control the values for different env and have it versioned automatically as it would be part of your code repo. Hope that makes sense. Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) link for web.config transformation.

[image]

Comment: Dotnet core app don't have web.config file. Op want web.config file which he added will don't modify when deployed.

Comment: True. But the question talks about making changes to web.config on app service. Hence my answer was directed towards that approach.